# Segregating the output result from select query as per primary key

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to get rows using below mySql statement:

```
+-----------------+
| text   | b_id   |
+-----------------|
|  a     |    1   |                                                                                                                                                                             
|  b     |    1   |                                                                                                                                                               
|  c     |    1   |                                                                                                                                                                              
|  e     |    2   | 
|  f     |    2   |
```

I want to get data in below format:

```
 +---------------+
 | b_id  | Text  |
 +-------+-------+
 |  1    | a,b,c |
 |  2    | e,f   |
```

I am using java/mysql api like below,but its giving me result for any b_id one by one,how to segregate it as per my requirement,any hints will be useful.

```
 Connection conn = new SqlServiceImpl().getConnection("hostName/dbName?",
        "user", "pwd", "");
  String query =
        "select desc.text,desc.b_id from desc,(select b_id,short_desc from bids where product_id=999) as bi where bi.b_id= desc.bug_id LIMIT 50;";
  Statement st = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

 while (rs.next())
  {
     int id = rs.getInt("b_id");
     String firstName = rs.getString("text");
     System.out.format("%s, %s\n", id, firstName);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Group by `b_id` column and `GROUP_CONCAT` the `text` column

```
select
  b_id,
  group_concat(text separator ',') text
from my_table
group by b_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer,but I am getting only 1 row,although I had used GROUP BY b_id at the end...

Comment: worked after running "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 18446744073709551615;"

Answer (score 2):

Simple query:

```
SELECT b_id, GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR ',') as text FROM test1 GROUP BY b_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY b_id` at the end of your SQL statement, and use `GROUP_CONCAT(',', desc.text)` in your SELECT portion.